# JQuery reference variable with selector, wrong data

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a little problem in my jQuery code. I do things like that:

HTML :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="selector">....</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$ref = $('.parent .selector');
$parent = $('.parent');

$ref.size() --> 1 
$parent.append('<div class="selector">....</div>');
$ref.size() --> always 1  ...
```

So what the use of store in vars... If i don't use reference var, all is good.
Thanks.

Comment: Caching the result is only good when you do not add or remove elements dynamically. If you do, the set of elements that matchs the selector is no longer the same, and it then makes sense to query again.

Comment: jQuery only selects the elements that currently *exist*. If you change the structure of the document, you have to *reselect* the elements.

Answer (score 2):

By the time you store the object in `$ref` it only has one child so it will always show `1`
You have to go through the DOM again after appending a new item.

```
$ref = $('.parent .selector');
$parent = $('.parent');

$ref.size() --> 1 
$parent.append('<div class="selector">....</div>');
$('.parent .selector').size() --> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Put like

```
$('<div class="selector">....</div>').appendTo($parent);
$parent.size(); --> gives 2
```

You need to append the div after the div class `selector`

Comment: Both are same I think...See iam appending to $ref

Comment: Excuse me but this is not the correct use of append in jQuery.

Comment: I know, i'm just giving the other method for a more global view.

Comment: Won't that append `.selector` into `.selector` instead of `parent`?

Comment: Yes it will add to every element in the collection actually, i didn't even see that

Comment: You can see my edit now...thnks @Virus721 I think it will be better option

Comment: Tht's Y i have appended to $parent